# Android Gradle - aar file

Tags: android, gradle

In my project i'm using few aar project dependencies file which i uploaded in maven repository. Now i have updated my new aar file in the same location.

I tried deleting local build folder in my project and started generating gradle build, but still it is taking old aar file from local folder and not from the repository.

How to delete local aar file and download new aar file from repository ?

Comment: Did you try running gradle with --refresh-dependencies flag?